# Stop numbering for paragraph in reledmac / reledpar

Tags: double-sided, reledmac, reledpar, parallel-texts

**TL;DR In a parallel type setting environment using reledmac / reledpar, I want to exclude some paragraphs from being numbered.**

I am currently creating a Latex document in a twoside class which contains a     bilingual text: On the left side (the left page) there is always a latin text     and on the right side (the right page) there is the german translation. For this     I am using reledpar. I have stanzas (astanza) on the left side and the     translation on the right side and I always let a headline / title preceed the actual stanza / translation.

Some poems on the left side nevertheless are followed by an annotation by the original author. Those are of course not indented as the rest of the stanzas and therefore are put into *\pstart \pend* pairs instead of the *astanza environment*. Now my problem is that those paragraphs containing the annotations are also numbered and I do not know how to stop that. **I read through the manual of reledpar / reledmac and tried using *\skipnumbering \hidenumbering* and *\hidenumberingonleftpage* , but non of it worked.**
How can I stop the numbering of some paragraphs in an otherwise numbered scenario?

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[]{reledmac}
\usepackage[]{reledpar}

% Set stanza indents
\setstanzaindents{8,5,6}
\setcounter{stanzaindentsrepetition}{2}

% Print a line number for every second line on the left side
\firstlinenum{2}
\linenumincrement{2}

% Disable the line numbering on the right side
\firstlinenumR{1000000000}

\begin{document}
\large
    \begin{pages}
    \begin{Leftside}
        \beginnumbering
            \begin{astanza}
                verse verse verse 1!&
                verse verse verse 2!&
                verse verse verse 3!&
                verse verse verse 4!\&
            \end{astanza}
            \pstart
                Some other text which should not be in verse form and therefore not numbered (basically an annotation which still will be translated). Let's just make it longer so we can see how it looks when spread over multiple lines.
            \pend
        \endnumbering
    \end{Leftside}
    \begin{Rightside}
        \beginnumbering
            \pstart
                This is a translation paragraph. Still just a translation paragraph. There is nothing interesting in here, please move on.
            \pend
            \pstart
                This is a translation paragraph. Still just a translation paragraph. There is nothing interesting in here, please move on.
            \pend
        \endnumbering
    \end{Rightside}
    \end{pages}
\Pages
\end{document}
```

This results in the following left page and right page:
[image: Left page] [image: Right page]

Here is also the resulting [PDF](https://mega.nz/#!g25HDaJI!qW9pPSyRlPlmvZ23RHYSlcG-XAwt_0cgtMfi9ull2V8)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `\skipnumbering` skip line number for a specific line. That is, in this line, line number is nore increased, nore printed.
2. `\hidenumbering` hide line number for a specific line. That is, in this line, line number is increased but not printed.
3. `\hidenumberingonleftpage` is the same, but it applies only when the line  is on a left page.

What you need is to "freeze" line number increasing and showing in a paragraph.
§5.4.2 of reledmac handbook is for you. It explains the `startlock`…`endlock` macro.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[]{reledmac}
\usepackage[]{reledpar}

% Set stanza indents
\setstanzaindents{8,5,6}
\setcounter{stanzaindentsrepetition}{2}

% Print a line number for every second line on the left side
\firstlinenum{1}
\linenumincrement{1}

% Disable the line numbering on the right side
\firstlinenumR{1000000000}

\begin{document}
\large
    \begin{pages}
    \begin{Leftside}
        \beginnumbering
            \begin{astanza}
                verse verse verse 1!&
                verse verse verse 2!&
                verse verse verse 3!&
                verse verse verse 4!\&
            \end{astanza}
            
            \pstart\startlock
                Some other text which should not be in verse form and therefore not numbered (basically an annotation which still will be translated). Let's just make it longer so we can see how it looks when spread over multiple lines.\endlock
            \pend \endlock
             \begin{astanza}
                verse verse verse 1!&
                verse verse verse 2!&
                verse verse verse 3!&
                verse verse verse 4!\&
            \end{astanza}
            
        \endnumbering
    \end{Leftside}
    \begin{Rightside}
        \beginnumbering
            \pstart
                This is a translation paragraph. Still just a translation paragraph. There is nothing interesting in here, please move on.
            \pend
            \pstart
                This is a translation paragraph. Still just a translation paragraph. There is nothing interesting in here, please move on.
            \pend
             \begin{astanza}
                verse verse verse 1!&
                verse verse verse 2!&
                verse verse verse 3!&
                verse verse verse 4!\&
            \end{astanza}
            
        \endnumbering
    \end{Rightside}
    \end{pages}
\Pages
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Maïeul! That was exactly what I was looking for!